# Error when closing Qt app on dev computer, not reported elsewhere

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.8

I am hoping that someone can shed some light on the issue I am experiencing. Our application is crashing when it is exited. This is the error I see in gdb.

```
Catchpoint 1 (exception thrown)
__cxa_throw (obj=0x19c1f388, tinfo=0xc450f8, dest=0)
    at ../../../../gcc-4.4.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h:234
        234     ../../../../gcc-4.4.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h: No such file
or directory.
    in ../../../../gcc-4.4.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h
Current language:  auto; currently c++
```

I am using Qt Creator 2.4.1 using the built in "Qt 4.8.1 for Desktop MinGw (Qt SDK)" libs.

Any help would be appreciated. I feel that this is an issue with GCC 4.4 as there have been a few quirks with it.

**EDIT** Backtrace

```
(gdb) bt
#0  __cxa_throw (obj=0x199ed1e8, tinfo=0xc450f8, dest=0)
at ../../../../gcc-4.4.0/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/unwind-cxx.h:234
#1  0x007594fd in boost::this_thread::interruptible_wait ()
#2  0x007de101 in boost::detail::basic_cv_list_entry::wait (this=0x1a3fbdf8,
abs_time=
  {start = 0, milliseconds = 18446744073709551615, relative = true, abs_time
= {<boost::date_time::base_time<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::date_time::cou
nted_time_system<boost::date_time::counted_time_rep<boost::posix_time::millisec_
posix_time_system_config> > >> = {<boost::less_than_comparable<boost::posix_time
::ptime, boost::equality_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time:
:ptime, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::fals
e_t>, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::true_t
>> = {<boost::less_than_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::equality_co
mparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::empt
y_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::false_t> >> = {<boost::equality
_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::e
mpty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::false_t>> = {<boost::equalit
y_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_t
ime::ptime> >> = {<boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>> = {<No d
ata fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data
fields>}, time_ = {time_count_ = {value_ = 9223372036854775806}}}, <No data fiel
ds>}, static max_non_infinite_wait = 4294967294})
at c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/boost/thr
ead/win32/condition_variable.hpp:94
#3  0x007dfbeb in boost::detail::basic_condition_variable::do_wait<boost::unique
_lock<boost::mutex> > (this=0xda81b0, lock=@0x15b1fe7c, abs_time=
  {start = 0, milliseconds = 18446744073709551615, relative = true, abs_time
 = {<boost::date_time::base_time<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::date_time::cou
nted_time_system<boost::date_time::counted_time_rep<boost::posix_time::millisec_
posix_time_system_config> > >> = {<boost::less_than_comparable<boost::posix_time
::ptime, boost::equality_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time:
:ptime, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::fals
e_t>, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::true_t
>> = {<boost::less_than_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::equality_co
mparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::empt
y_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::false_t> >> = {<boost::equality
_comparable<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::e
mpty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>, boost::detail::false_t>> = {<boost::equalit
y_comparable1<boost::posix_time::ptime, boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_t
ime::ptime> >> = {<boost::detail::empty_base<boost::posix_time::ptime>> = {<No d
ata fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data fields>}, <No data
fields>}, time_ = {time_count_ = {value_ = 9223372036854775806}}}, <No data fiel
ds>}, static max_non_infinite_wait = 4294967294})
at c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/boost/thr
ead/win32/condition_variable.hpp:228
#4  0x007c5867 in boost::condition_variable::wait (this=0xda81b0,
m=@0x15b1fe7c)
at c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/boost/thr
ead/win32/condition_variable.hpp:318
#5  0x007769c8 in CCheckQueue<CScriptCheck>::Loop (this=0xda81a8,
fMaster=false) at ../Feathercoin-0.8.5/src/checkqueue.h:93
#6  0x00776cd1 in CCheckQueue<CScriptCheck>::Thread (this=0xda81a8)
at ../Feathercoin-0.8.5/src/checkqueue.h:127
#7  0x0043933f in ThreadScriptCheck ()
at ../Feathercoin-0.8.5/src/main.cpp:1657
#8  0x007d8546 in boost::detail::thread_data<void (*)()>::run (this=0x7a27140)
at c:/qtsdk/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.4.0/../../../../include/boost/thr
ead/detail/thread.hpp:117
#9  0x00758bf0 in boost::(anonymous namespace)::thread_start_function ()
#10 0x00757996 in boost::(anonymous namespace)::ThreadProxy ()
#11 0x76d0336a in KERNEL32!BaseCleanupAppcompatCacheSupport ()
from C:\Windows\syswow64\kernel32.dll
#12 0x151e2e50 in ?? ()
#13 0x15b1ffd4 in ?? ()
#14 0x77a39f72 in ntdll!RtlpNtSetValueKey ()
from C:\Windows\system32\ntdll.dll
#15 0x151e2e50 in ?? ()
#16 0x6f8b48f8 in ?? ()
#17 0x00000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Isn't the exit code more helpful?

Comment: Can you check that you don't try to access to a widget after its parent closed (the parent deletes its children with itself) ?

Comment: what's the backtrace in gdb?

Comment: Edited with backtrace. Exit code is not helpful at all.

Comment: I don't understand this error fully, but I recall that when we had it in my previous company we had to change GCC to some newer version. I think it's some GCC bug.